# Repetitions in a sequence mod m

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

For what $a , b$  there will be no repetitions in the finite sequence of length $m=2k$ under $\mod m$:
$$\{a, a-b, 2a-b, 2a-2b, \ldots, ka-(k-1)b,~ ka-kb\}$$

My work:
This is like taking $a$ steps forward, then $b$ steps backward on a *circle*.
This sequence is expressed in closed form as
$$x_{2n} = n(a-b)\\x_{2n+1} = n(a-b)+a$$
Say $n_1\lt n_2\lt m$, then two values in the sequence are equal means
$$n_1(a-b)\equiv n_2(a-b)+a\pmod m$$

Rearranging
$$(n_1-n_2)(a-b)\equiv a\pmod m$$

From here can I conclude the sequence has no repetition values when $a-b$ doesn't divide $a$ ?   I'm a bit rusty with modular arithmetic.
What happens if $a-b$ divides $m$? Pretty sure $m$ plays a role here, but I feel stuck.. Any help?